# Rename column headers in CSV file with special characters

Tags: powershell, csv

My headers are the following :

```
Avis,N° Invent.,Cd.Srv.Cl.,Client Name
```

I have found this code to change my headers

```
Import-Csv "$treatmentfolder\data.csv" |
    Select-Object @{expression={$_.Avis}; label='avis'} |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$treatmentfolder\data2.csv"
```

How do I change the header names where the characters are space, `.`,`°`, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select and rename a particular field put the name of the field whose name you want to change in quotes:

```
... | Select-Object @{n='no_invent';e={$_.'N° Invent.'}}, ... | ...
```

To replace a particular field exclude the original field in addition to creating a renamed field:

```
... | Select-Object *,@{n='no_invent';e={$_.'N° Invent.'}} -Exclude 'N° Invent.' | ...
```

Comment: I tried it but it deletes everything and adds `no_invent` in the first cell.

Comment: You have to put all of the headers that you want in the Select-Object portion of the pipe separated by commas. Select-Object only leaves the specified properties on the object (sort of).

Comment: @EBGreen Could you give me an example of how to write it, please?

Answer (score 3):

As a CSV is just a text file, we can treat this as a string replacement on the first line of the file (array item `0`)

This options uses a simple regex expression to remove anything that isn't: `0-9` `a-z` `A-Z` `,` or  (space), so just amend any other chars you want to keep into the regex. This will work on any header names.

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "$treatmentfolder\data.csv"

$content[0] = $content[0] -replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z, ]'

Set-Content "$treatmentfolder\data.csv"
```

The other option is to chain multiple `replace` together, this enables you to add/remove/change headers however you want. But unlike the option above it is hardcoded to the specific header names, so not as simple to run different files through.

```
$content[0] = $content[0] -replace 'NÂ° Invent.','No_Invent' -replace 'Cd.Srv.Cl.','Cd-Srv-Cl'
```